# how to make no limit on maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an ASP.NET (C#) 4.0 WCF application. I got message error:

> Error : The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I have increased it into

```
maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152"
```

it works fine. But I am afraid that next time may be it will be over the quota again.

Can I set this `maxBufferSize` and `maxReceivedMessageSize` with no limit ?

thanks you in advance

Answer (score 6):

> Can I set this maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize with no limit
>   ?

**No.** You can not do that.

Set your values to Max like:

```
  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

[MaxBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.maxbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx) is of type `int`. So the max value it can support is [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) (2147483647) to avail the maximum allowable size. *(`Int.MaxValue` is just one byte shy of 2 GB of data)*

[MaxReceivedMessageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.100).aspx) on the other hand is of type `long` or [`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and the max value it supports is: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: In 4.5, the max value is int64 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.maxreceivedmessagesize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Hoppe, its `Int64` for .Net framework 3.0 and higher for `MaxReceivedMessageSize`, `MaxBufferSize` on the other hand is of type `int` in .Net framework 3.0 and higher. Thanks for the comment, it led me to edit my mistake in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot set it to "no limit" - how would you handle a limitlessly large message, anyway?

The maximum you can set it to is 2 billion (`int.MaxValue` in .NET) - which corresponds to 2 GB (2'147'483'648 bytes) of data.

Is that enough for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're maxing out your buffer with big uploads or downloads, consider streaming as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You should change buffersize, if you're using dynamically use this code

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.ProxyAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort));
        binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue; //IMPORTANT
        binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue; //IMPORTANT
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;//IMPORTANT
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
```

if you're using webconfig use this code

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" 
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
             maxArrayLength="200000000"
             maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```